# How can I get the instance of a static class which is initiated inside static block in servlet filter?

Tags: java, servlets, reflection

In my Servlet there is an object B initiated during load time. The initialization of the object B is in a static block like this:

```
FilterA implements Filter{ 
  private static B b = new B(); 
  static {b.setText("This is B");}
  doFilter(){...}
}

class B{
   private String text;
   public void setText(String s){
      this.text=s;
   }
   public String getText(){
      return this.text;
   }
 }
```

where FilterA is a Servlet filter defined in web.xml.

What I am doing is writing a new Servlet filter (filterB) to modify object B. The filterB is placed right after filterA in web.xml as below.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>filterA</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.FilterA</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>filterB</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.FilterB</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Given that Reflection is the only solution I can use in filter B to retrieve the instance of of class B. Is there any method can be adopted to retrieve it?

I don't think Class.forName() is suitable for this case because I am not going to create any new instance of class B but only to retrieve the existing instance .

//new thing goes here

I am writing a simple test class to simulate the case. Please take the following code as the point:

```
package com.jm.test;

public class AIAItest {

    private static BB bb = new BB();

    static{
        bb.setText("sb");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {

            //TODO use reflection to get the  instance of BB, is it possible?
            //do not simply refer to bb


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

class BB{
    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with java servlets, but you should be able to access class B just by doing FilterA.b.

Comment: Can you modify the source of FilterA?

Comment: Not really cuz FilterA is built in JAR which is provided by third party...

Comment: If that's not he only modification you need in that filter you can look towards [javaassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) to modify 3rd party compiled bytecode rather than modifying it via Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to code it using reflection, the main points are:

- for static fields, there is no instance needed for the Field.get() method
- you must make the Field public

Like this:

```
Field f = AIAItest.class.getField("bb");
f.setAccessible(true); // effectively make it public
BB bb = (BB)f.get(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that `b` is `public` and `static` in `FilterA`, a direct static reference to it should work. In `FilterB`, this code should work

```
B b = FilterA.b;
```

Comment: thx for ur answer first. it was my mistake writing it public, it should be private  actually. That's why i am thinking about the solution of reflection.